# Div has equal height

Tags: css

I've this code

```css
.container {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.col {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.col:first-child{
  float: left;
}

.col:last-child{
  float: right;
}

.text {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="text">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam placeat amet dolore asperiores et omnis voluptas dolorum natus nobis. Ad, provident exercitationem tempora vel laudantium iure libero possimus voluptates ipsa.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="img">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/480x150">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/480x50">
    </div>
     <div class="text">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Without having any height declared. I want my two `.col` have the same height.
I need to take care about responsive too.

I already try to set a fixed height to my last `.text` div but it does not help me..

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox can do that:

```css
.container {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.col {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background:plum;
}
.text {
  background-color: lightblue;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="text">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam placeat amet dolore asperiores et omnis voluptas dolorum natus nobis. Ad, provident exercitationem tempora vel laudantium iure libero possimus voluptates ipsa.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="img">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/480x150">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/480x50">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```